# How to pass enum validation in Flow.js

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I defined a enum type by `$Keys<typeof obj>`, and using this type in a function as an argument type.

When calling this function with a defined enum directly, like `loadList('Type1')`, it works fine.

But when the argument is read from other place, like user input or ajax response, I cannot cast the `string` or `?string` to `ListType` type.

As the codes explain below.

```
/* @flow */

const listTypes = Object.freeze({
  Type1: 'type_1',
  Type2: 'type_2',
  Type3: 'type_3',
});

type ListType = $Keys<typeof listTypes>;

function loadList(type: ListType): void {
  return;
}

const type: string = 'Type2';
loadList(type); // fail
loadList((type: ListType)) // still fail

if (listTypes[type]) {
  loadList(type); // continue fail
}

if (listTypes[type]) {
  loadList(listTypes[type]); // pass but should fail
}
```

So only one way to make both flow pass and enum works as expected, I should define the value in `listTypes` same as the keys.

Here's the link of [Try in flow.org](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzBgEsCAVATwAcBTXMAXjAHkAjAKxo3wDooAnGjQBeNABQBvVGDCVaARgBcYAOT5qNAPryVAGmmyNAJmVqNmo3oNyaAZlPram21YC+ASgDc6RzTAAZUnwbRjAAEgBpGgpcAB5fOCgiIJtcAD5vVCgAV2xuYhwiOABDABNAgjFfZQrgjXdlADc4YlKwKRlBfGz+bG9XdCw8QmqwAn5ibABzUJUbS294Mtqq+s8wYGAwKGLiGFQl8qCxVdoalPr3Da2CPZht3f3UYiSxEnINXABtXwBdK46RWWx18XmuYCG+Em2T8Oz2qAGz1e7zqtG+fwBBkOKxRqR+Gn+602YCoxVw9FY2UIuAAFnBsjA2nD9q4gA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to convert any arbitrary `string` (such as `window.location.search`), you could write a function that converts it to a `ListType`. For example,

```
function strToListType(str: string): ListType {
  if (str === 'Type1' || str === 'Type2' || str === 'Type3') {
    return str;
  } else {
    throw new Error('Invalid string');
  }
}
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBANgS2gFQJ4AcCmEYF4YDyARgFabBQB0AZgE6aYBemAFAN4BQMMaWAjAC4YAcigZMAfT7CANFx7iATENHiJi2fN6YAzCrFYJOzQF8AlAG4OHA5hgAZJFG14YAEgDSmVBAA8tkGp4J20IAD4rDmoAVzAKBHB4EABDABNHaBZbIQzncTMhADcQBFSYTm56KGjaMCsTaxi4qASwGGhaZBBc7RYOoQ6EMABzAocQ8XL5BCC+qFo8XHxhbWkYAB919vnF5e0NDa2O3ZFtYzMp7krMatrt2ituExhMOAg7CquoAAtaEAB3GBgTCAgCitD+tBYwgAkmBCslEGVBiNhJZ5A0GkA)

Unfortunately, you have to explicitly retype the keys in order for Flow not to complain. (You cannot do `listTypes[str] !== undefined` or `Object.keys(listTypes).includes(str)` as of v0.98.0. Perhaps there is another way to get Flow to refine `str` correctly without explicitly declaring each key, but I couldn't find one.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So according to explicitily all keys in a if condition statement, define the value same as the key in enum definitions maybe a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

try changing the type variable's type from string to ListType

```
const type: ListType = 'Type2';
```

Comment: But when got variable from other function, like window.location.search, it will raise an error about cannot cast string to ListType.